# Wordpress - Image lightbox with different image when clicked

Tags: wordpress, image, gallery, lightbox

For my wordpress site, I need some images arranged in a grid and when one is clicked a specific (different) image is displayed bigger. I thought that there maybe is a lightbox/gallery plugin, where one enters the link for the small and big picture, and I can just use the link to a different image instead of to the same one, but bigger. Does anyone know a plugin that works like that? Or any other way to make that work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[WP Gallery Custom Links](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-custom-links-to-gallery-images-in-wordpress/)" plugin to set different image link by using "custom URL" option.

Simply go to a post or page and create a new gallery. You will see the custom link meta fields for individual images in a gallery.

Comment: But I don't want to visit another site when the image is clicked, I want another image to be "lightbox"-like displayed
Like this for example: http://www.html-seminar.de/bilder/lightbox-bildergalerie-23-browser-ansicht.png